# How to pass information about user and password to the command 'flask db migrate'

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I  am following an online Flask tutorial and I get stuck at point where you do the first database migration. At the command

```
$ flask db migrate
```

I get the error message

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError)
(1045, "Access denied for user 'counter_app'@'localhost' (using password: NO)") 
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Unfortuneately, the link in the error message does not provide adequate help, but I am pretty certain I know what the problem is. With the command, I am trying to connect to the database without using a password ("using password: NO"), however, for the user in question, 'counter_app', there is a password set in the .flaskenv file like so:

```
FLASK_APP='manage.py'
FLASK_ENV=development
SECRET_KEY='my_secret_key'
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USERNAME='counter_app'
DB_PASSWORD='mypassword'
DATABASE_NAME='counter'
```

The file appklication.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

# setup db
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # Load config
    app.config.from_pyfile('settings.py')

    # initialize db
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate = Migrate(app, db)

    # import blueprints
    from counter.views import counter_app

    # register blueprints
    app.register_blueprint(counter_app)

    return app
```

then loads through app.config.from_pyfile('settings.py'); settings.py looks like this:

```
import os

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
DB_USERNAME=os.environ['DB_USERNAME']
DB_PASSWORD=os.environ['DB_PASSWORD']
DB_HOST=os.environ['DB_HOST']
DATABASE_NAME=os.environ['DATABASE_NAME']
DB_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://%s:%s@%s:3306/%s' % (DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST, DATABASE_NAME)
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = DB_URI
```

If this worked properly, the this sequence should set the DB_USERNAME, which it does, but it should also set DB_PASSWORD, which it does not. So the problem appears to be the flask command does not get that it should be reading the information in the .flaskenv file and then to use the the password when migrating the database. When giving the command, I am in the same directory as the .flaskenv file. Also, I am able to login in to the database manually, so I know the username and password from the .flaskenv file are correct.

The documentation flask regarding command line option is very terse and does not give any examples of how to specifying the database user and password. So how can I force the 'flask db migrate' command to use the right user and password?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the tutorial, please?

Comment: It's paid for Udemy course, so it's behind a paywall (https://www.udemy.com/from-zero-to-flask). However, the sample files are available on github at https://github.com/fromzeroedu/itfc-visitor-counter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the author of the course. The issue that has come up is that the latest packages for MySQL on Homebrew have been updated to install MySQL 8.0. The course assumes that you are installing MySQL 5.7, which was the default Homebrew package a month ago.

To fix this issue, please install the specific version of MySQL in your local system.

If you have installed it already, uninstall first, using `brew remove mysql`.

Then, install using `brew install mysql@5.7`.

The issue is that there is a new authentication mechanism for MySQL 8.0+ that encrypts the password automatically.

If you still want to use MySQL 8.0, you can alter the `counter_app` user to use the password by doing the following:

`ALTER USER 'counter_app'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mypassword';`

Or if you want to create it from scratch, do:

`CREATE USER 'counter_app'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mypassword';`

Comment: Thanks for for answer (a for a great course). Redid everything from start, including removing and then reinstalling mysql. I copied the files from the repo and as far as I can tell, the .flaskenv and settings.py are the same (see https://github.com/niklasrudemo/visitor-counter).  Adding `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` yields this: `(Pdb) current_app.config['DB_USERNAME']
'counter_app'
(Pdb) current_app.config['DB_PASSWORD']
'mypassword'`. Yet `flask db migrate` still fails in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `.env` and `.flaskenv` configuration dotfiles, you need to have `python-dotenv` installed and configured.

[python-dotenv: Getting Started](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv#getting-started)

[flask: Environmental Variables from dotenv](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/cli/#environment-variables-from-dotenv)

Instead of having a separate `.flaskenv`, most projects I've seen have a single `.env` file containing all of the application secrets, which is kept out of version control.

Comment: Using python-dotenv seems like a good thing, however this is not what the tutorial is using and it manages to read the username for the database, so that part is working in principle. The problem seems to be that either it does not read the password from the .flaskenv file, or it does not understand it should use it when migrating

Comment: In the "From Zero to Flask" course, the last lesson in "Say Hello World" is titled "Python Dot Env for PythonAnywhere." The description mentions adding `python-dotenv` to the `requirements.txt` file. Once you do that, you will need to run `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: You are right, Richard, the example does indeed already use `python-dotenv==0.8.2`.

I tried running the application.py line by line in the interpreter and when I get to `app.config.from_pyfile('settings.py')` I get this error: `KeyError: 'DB_USERNAME'`. So it seems like reading the environment variables in the settings.py does not work properly.